# Matching colors for customer's display

Tags: color, website-design

I realize this a difficult issue to solve but still, maybe someone can suggest a good compromise. When designing a website on my system the colors look the way I want but when checking them on the customer displays they look horrible (in some cases). Is there a way to solve this issue? What would be the best approach?
Thank you.